# 29 Feb date query. Add one day to the date where condition in SQL statement if specific date is invalid

Tags: mysql, laravel, date, leap-year

I have a problem with dates of 29 Feb.

I have a query that receives the year as dynamic parameter from PHP/Laravel. The month and day are not inserted. The query that is sent to the database includes the current year from current date. I want to compare the date, against a specific column in the database, if the date is invalid (ex: 02-29-2019), I want to compare the date against 03-01-2019

```
->whereRaw("DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(?),MONTH(sendDate),DAY(sendDate))) 
>= birthdate",[$date])
```

The query above returns null if the resulting concatenated date is invalid ex: 2019-02-29

My desired PUSEDO Code/function:

```
if "DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(?),MONTH(sendDate),DAY(sendDate) is NULL
and MONTH(sendDate)=03 and DAY(sendDate)=01" THEN 
WHERE Birthdate>= DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(?),03,01)
ELSE
WHERE Birthdate>= DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(?),MONTH(sendDate),DAY(sendDate)
```

Is there a function in MySQL that can help overcome this problem? The problem with my current query

Answer (score 0):

Below code checks the string in format yyyy-mm-dd. 
If it is a a valid date then converts it to date.
Else returns the first day of the next month as date.

Below is the sample code:

```
DECLARE @T AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @T = '2019-02-29'
select  @T as Original,
        TRY_PARSE(@T AS DATE USING 'en-gb') as DateIfValid,
        TRY_PARSE(LEFT(@T,4) + '-' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@T,6,2) AS tinyint)+1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-1' AS DATE USING 'en-gb') as Replacement
```

Returns

```
Original   DateIfValid Replacement
---------- ----------- -----------
2019-02-29 NULL        2019-03-01
```

And below code demonstrates how to use it as a function:

```
select  @T as Original,
       ,ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(@T AS DATE USING 'en-gb'), TRY_PARSE(LEFT(@T,4) + '-' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@T,6,2) AS tinyint)+1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-1' AS DATE USING 'en-gb')) as FinalResult


    Original   FinalResult
    ---------- -----------
    2019-02-29 2019-03-01
```

Hope this helps,   BR

Answer (score -2):

No, there is not.

However if can help you to know that leap years are once every four years: 2008, 2012, 2016...
Considered as integer numbers they are also multiple of 4. So, if a year is a leap year then:

`YEAR % 4 = 0`

You can try to use this at your advantage.

Comment: Note that it is not simply whether the year divides by 4 or not to determine whether it is a leap year, and just relying on this method will still return invalid dates (e.g. 1900 % 4 = 0, however it's not a leap year). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) for more details.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, but if it the table only refers to [years on this century it will hold](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/LeapYear.html#targetText=The%20complete%20list%20of%20leap,2040%2C%202044%2C%20and%202048.)! Someone may debate that this will be a Y2K all over again but it depends of what is the purpouse of the DB and what data stores

Comment: Yes, the two closest years that it affects are 1900 and 2100, so as long as the dates are within those bounds you'd get away with it. Although personally, I'd rather implement the full rules just in case!

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Assuming the century is a cheap way to get away with a design flaw.